# BIGINT in MySQL Changes a my number? Why does it do this?

Tags: php, mysql, biginteger, bigint

I'll try and keep this simple. I'm using a BIGINT data type on a MySQL database table. I have a function generating a unique random number that may span anywhere from 12 digits to 13 digest long.

When I insert into the database with a digit that is 12 digits in length, it enters it just fine,

but when I use a value that is 13 digits or longer, it seems like it rounds up or something. here is the

php

```
$defaultText = 'some string'; //just some string
$web_id = 12;
$element_id = 23112182735363; //case 1 (doesn't work)
//$element_id = 2311218333205; //case 2, does work ()
  mysql_query("INSERT INTO tableName (web_id, element_id, content)
  VALUES ($web_id, $element_id, '".mysql_real_escape_string($defaultText)."')");
```

results:
 in case one, it inserts a slightly different number, usually rounds up for some reason.

in case two, it inserts the number just fine! Maybe someone can help shed some light on this mystery! Thanks again!

the big int datatype:

```
bigint(200)
```

Comment: The bracket number is purely for display purposes - how many digits MySQL should display. It does not affect storage requirements internally at all - a bigint is always 64bits, whichs mean it'll have at most 20 digits. Telling MySQl to display 200 digits on a number that can never have more than 20 is rather pointless

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Numbers lose their precision from PHP_INT_MAX onwards. See also: http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.constants.php#constant.php-int-max

After that they are turned into floats which have limited precision and causes weird rounding issues. The only way to support BIGINT in PHP is by using strings.

Comment: Thank you kind sir, I hope this helps anyone else out there with the same issue. I changed it to string.

Answer (score 1):

I assumed you were talking about a 32-bit server. 
But in my server, PHP seemed not lose the precision.

`echo(PHP_INT_MAX . "<br/>"); 
$big_int = -6174803190685607000; 
echo($big_int . '<br/>');`

output

`9223372036854775807<br/>-6174803190685607000<br/>`

Sadly I still got the precision losing. I guessed it might because i used 'i' in prepare statement of mysqli, but I could not prove it.

Comment: Thank you for your response, and don't call me sally. ;)